# Error: The application ApplicationName needs to be rebuilt due to an inconsistency between the connected Mac and the local app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

When trying to build the iOS version of my Xamarin application I received the following error:

```
The application ApplicationName needs to be rebuilt due to an inconsistency between 
the connected Mac and the local app. Please rebuild the application and try
again.
```

I am using the following software:

1. Windows 10

   - Visual studio 2015 Community
   - Xamarin.iOS 9.4.2.24
   - Xamarin 4.0.1.145
2. OS X 10.11.3 El Capitan.

   - Xcode 7.2.1
   - Xamarin Studio 5.10.3
   - Mono 4.2.3
   - GTK+ 2.24.23
   - Xamarin.iOS 9.4.2.27
   - Xamarin.Android 6.0.2.1

Are there any work arounds for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting one of the following bugs:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37937

This should hopefully be fixed in Cycle 7 - [workaround here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37937#c0)

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37600

And this should hopefully be fixed in Cycle 6 SR 2 - [workaround in this comment](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37600#c6)

Comment: I have upgraded to Cycle 7 Alpha 2 and continue to observe the same error message.

Comment: It was fixed in a new release.

Answer (score 2):

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56054/the-application-xxx-needs-to-be-rebuilt-due-to-an-inconsistency

As suggested on the forum linked above, I found that disconnecting the Mac build agent and reconnecting fixed this issue.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I believe that is what I did, the essential part is that reconnecting to the build agent is a work-around for this issue and I linked to where I found this.

Comment: A link is always welcome. But, it suggested to put essential information. Because, if the content of linked page changes, website goes down, version changes, then your answer become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I was using Resharper's own "Build" feature. As soon as I disabled Resharper Build, everything worked fine.

Comment: It helped me too

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when you change build agents and there are conflicts between your local cache files and the ones created from your current build.

Delete the project folder created at /Users/{username}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/{projectName} on your Mac.  Clean, then rebuild.

You'll want to make sure all of the bin and obj folder contents are deleted.  You may have to do it manually.  Otherwise, the issue will persist.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same bug when I switched connections from one mac to another 
Try changing the iOS Build Configuration -> "Debug" instead of "Active(Debug)" and Platform-> "iPhoneSimulator" instead of "Active (iPhoneSimulator)"